# jQuery - independently set each element height to child element height for each instance

Tags: jquery, height

I have multiple html blocks in a jQuery cycle instance, like so:

```
<div class="pane" id="...">
 <div class="title">
  <span>...</span>
  <div class="sS">...</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

`.pane` is the cycle slide. I want to get the height of each of the spans independently (as they contain different amounts of text so some wrap onto two lines on smaller screens).

With the height calculated, I want to apply this value to the height of the parent `.title` - independently (without having to work it all out manually for each pane based on ID).

So far I have:

```
 $(".pane").each(function() {
    var tpheight =  $(this).find("span").outerHeight()
    $(this).find(".title").css({"height" : tpheight + "px"})
})
```

which sort of works (inclusion of "px" makes no difference) but the first span comes out as the correct height but all the other spans in the other panes are too short. I'm using `outerHeight` as I need to include the padding. This is the page I'm working on:

http://test.soundvaultstudios.co.uk/services

A lot of other posts talk about getting the height of the tallest element and applying that value to every other element, but I want the values all worked out independently. The reason I'm doing this is when you hover over the pane the title div gets a style of `height:auto` to reveal the contents of `.sS` , then on mouseleave the height of the title div reverts back to the height of the span. I hope that makes sense, have a look at the site to see what I mean. The hover function generates the correct height changes however, but I want the page to load in the same way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the page, it looks like there's a bigger problem with your javascript.  When looking at some of the titles, when you mouse over a larger one, then it moves over and you mouse over a smaller one then it falls down, the title gets sort of hidden.  It seems like you might need to rework the code entirely.  Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi ntg, my code is actually pretty simple, as simple as I can make it really, the cycle functionality is exactly how I wanted it. The hover function I have set does exactly what it should, it's just the page load that doesn't.

Comment: Hey Joe, when I took a look at your site, the script was getting pretty buggy. Try loading the page fresh, mouse over so the hover works, wait for the cycle to happen a couple times, then hover out and you will see the titles get buried lower than they should be.  I understand its simple but it seems there are other issues that you will need to work out before you can get your desired action done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where I was going wrong. My `each` function was setup perfectly fine, it was the position of it in relation to the `cycle` initialisation that was the problem (It was causing script placed after it to malfunction). Putting the `cycle` initialisation last in my block (or at least after my each function) has worked as I intended. If anyone sees this question who's using Cycle, take note of the order of your script, Cycle last!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try...

```
$(".pane").each(function() {
    var tpheight =  $(this).find("span").outerHeight()
    $(this).find(".title").outerHeight(tpheight);
 })
```

also, if you're setting css it should be......

```
 $(this).find(".title").css("height",tpheight)
```

not......

```
$(this).find(".title").css({"height" : tpheight + "px"})
```

Comment: Hi Sam, unfortunately I'd already tried using `.outerHeight`, `.height` as well as CSS and they all have the same effect. The issue is with the each loop function rather than what I am using to set the height. Thanks for trying though.